# proxies.ExceptionSerialisingRpcOpsProxy.log - Error during RPC invocation [errorCode=19t75of]

Tags: corda

When running a flow in Corda via RPC (or via the Shell) an "Error during RPC invocation" is returned with no further information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error has been returned from the node via RPC. The RPC connection hides the original error in order to stop possible privacy leaks. If you check the logs of the node there should be more information on the error.